# Is it possible to disable HAMX feature for an AVD based on Intel x86 CPU?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I created some AVDs in Android Studio V3.5. All these AVDs are based on Intel x86 CPU. 
But I failed to start any of them because any HAXM devices couldn't be found.

I have enabled VT-x in BIOS settings. When I tried to install 'Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager V7.0.5', it reported "failed to configure driver unknown error. failed to open driver.".

So, is it possible to disable HAMX feature for an AVD based on Intel x86 CPU?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the myAVD.ini, there is not any options for HAXM. So, maybe it's no way to disable the HAMX feature required for an AVD based on Intel x86 CPU.

But the good news is, I finally worked out the "failed to configure driver unknown error. failed to open driver." issue now after my continuous google and studying. My HAXM driver works well now.